# Optimizing Firebase query for speed: search Users by city

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-schema, nosql

Scenario: I have a Users node which stores their location (city & country). I want to find all users that reside in a particular city. Then per city, I want to filter on *roomType* and finally sort Users by their score.

Problem: City & Country are *string* fields, so it will be VERY resource intensive string_comparison query to iterate over all the Users to first match the country & then the city.

What can I do to make this search faster?

One possible approach: Convert the City + Country "location_pair" into a numeric value (say *int_val_location_pair*). Then do a integer comparison on *int_val_location_pair*. This will be much faster than doing two string comparisons on country & city. Of course, I will have to store mapping as a separate node.

There aren't that many cities in the world (approx 4,000,000) so I can easily use a 32 bytes integer to represent all cities in the world. Plus realistically, I will get Users from at max 10,000 different cities signed up.

schema can be something like this:

```
$Users:
    name:
    city:
    country:
    $int_val_location_pair:
    score:
    roomType:   
$int_val_location_pair:
    city:
    country:
```

Question: Is this a good approach??

If yes, I have next concern: At time of registration, when the user fills in country & city, I want to create a new value for *int_val_location_pair* automatically only IF the location_pair (city & country) does not exist in database.

In this case how to make sure there is no duplication of *int_val_location_pair*?  Say 10 people are registering **all at same time** for same location (which does not exists in db). They all query the database & get confirmation that location_pair doesnt exist & so end up creating a new value for *int_val_location_pair* causing duplicates. How should I avoid this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep a list of users ids for each location in a tree?

```
usersByLocation
  $country
    $city
      uid1: true
      uid2: true
```

With that you can simply look up the UIDs for the users in a specific city with:

```
ref.child("United States").child("San Francisco").on("child_added"...
```

Comment: I thought about that but lets say there are int total 10,000 cities where app Users reside & say each city has 5,000 Users. Wouldn't that be a problem? Plus the other part of my application (which I didnt mention originally) will take these 5,000 Users in the city & then do additional filtering on them. I have one more string comparison & one sort operation to be done on the result of 5,000 Users.

Comment: The approach I showed uses no querying and no filtering. Which means that it scales extremely well. But it's hard to optimize across such wide claims. Instead I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) to gain a better grasp of the topic.